# If I set true to `YAxisProps['reversed']`, The YAxis minimum value is not displayed

Tags: reactjs, recharts

If I set true to `YAxisProps['reversed']`, The YAxis minimum value is not displayed.

Is this what intended?
And,
How do I display value?

```
<YAxis reversed={true} />
```

## Example

https://codesandbox.io/s/recharts-playground-8t6bg